# I'm not in the stars, because I am ours

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm not in the stars, because I am ours.
>   If I'm active in line, you may not be fine.
>   If you have me today, you have something to say.
>   If you give me to your lover, she may find another.

What am I?

Include your reasoning for each line in your answer.

Comment: Rhyme tag is not applicable.

Comment: I think it rhymes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a:

> Fault

I'm not in the stars, because I am ours.

> Fault is not in the stars because the Fault is ours

If I'm active in line, you may not be fine.

> If a Fault is active in a line like the San Andrea then we are not fine

If you have me today, you have something to say.

> If you have a Fault today then you need to say that you are SORRY

If you give me to your lover, she may find another.

> If you give your lover a Fault than she will find another Fault in you...

Comment: She may find another "guy". Not fault :D

Comment: @MITU RAJ    After 40 years of marriage I can tell you that if you give your lover a reason to think that you have a fault she will be inclined to find other faults in you...Your experience may be that she would just go find another guy...

Comment: @Drt Actually, the hint alluded to "faulting" your lover, as in, finding a fault in or blaming your spouse. Also, the "finding another" part was intentionally ambiguous.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the first line is alluding to a famous bit of Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar*. ("The fault, dear Brutus, is not in our stars / But in ourselves".)